# Visual Studio project types Makefile and Utility

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022, uefi

I am creating a vcxproj project to build C code (UEFI) which builds with custom build steps. I need the source C and H files to display with full IntelliSense support, then when I hit F5, I want the project to build if any source file changed, then start Debug. If nothing changed, just start the Debugger. The Build just needs to run my command line commands, I do not need Visual Studio to use its C compiler and Linker. It seems the only way to build with custom steps is to set Configuration Type to either Makefile or Utility.

One problem with Makefile project is that it always builds the NMake command line even if I did not touch any files. Is there a way to configure build so that it only builds if any of the source files changed, like with Application or Dynamic Library project types?

Another problem (only with Makefile project) is that it forces IntelliSense to some C++ mode that marks all my CHAR16* L"Strings" as errors: a value type of const wchar_t* cannot be used to initialize an entry of type "CHAR16*". There are Additional Options under NMake IntelliSense menu, but no matter what I put there makes no difference. There is no documentation about what the available switches are and their effect. Is it possible to configure a Makefile project to C mode? BTW, VS2013 does not have this problem, it is only VS2019 and VS2022.

Utility project type does not have the above-mentioned problem with IntelliSense, but it always returns "build up-to-date" even when I change source files, which should set a dirty flag and cause a build. The build only starts when I select Rebuild. Is it possible to configure a Utility project to build when a source file changed?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the second part of my question, about wchar_t. For a regular C++ project (not a Makefile project) the solution is well known - go to C/C++ in the project configuration properties and set "Treat WChar_t As Built in Type" to No (/Zc:wchar_t-). However, there are no C/C++ settings in the Makefile project. The solution was to examine how a standard C++ project saves its parameters in the .VCXPROJ file and do the same in mine. Specifically for my issue, I added the following section:

```
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <WarningLevel>Level4</WarningLevel>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>MY_DEBUG</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <TreatWChar_tAsBuiltInType>false</TreatWChar_tAsBuiltInType>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

Setting *TreatWChar_tAsBuiltInType* to *false* did the trick. It also helped me adding the Preprocessor Definitions like MY_DEBUG, I think it would also work for other properties of the C/C++ project that are not accessible in Makefile project.